# How has computational linguistics contributed to the preservation of endangered languages?

Tags: computational-linguistics, endangered-languages, language-preservation

Computational tools and techniques had been applied to the field of historical linguistics, aiding in the analysis of old or endangered languages. This has contributed to the documentation and preservation of linguistic diversity.

How has computational linguistics contributed to the preservation of endangered languages?

Comment: Has it it really aided preservation? Computational linguistics is predominantly analytical, whereas language preservation is dependent on the primary work of language description, as well as social/political advocation, and resource production (such as for vernacular programs in schools.) Maybe it's most useful for machine translation, for example in the initial drafts of Bible translations (which has sometimes been a driving factor behind languages persisting.)

Comment: @curiousdannii On the other hand I'd be very surprised if a usable machine translation system preceded a Bible translation for a particular language.

Comment: @Draconis I know they do use automatic translations for initial drafts now, but they're probably much simpler than most ML translation systems and require the source and target languages to have very similar syntaxes. Probably still counts as computational linguistics though?

Comment: Social and political advocacy, yes.